# npm & ionic shows different version in different folders

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I have weird issue with installing ionic and npm.

Until yesterday, I could build an app without any issue.
I've tried to update ionic 2 version and it's updated to 2.1.18, but when I check

> ionic -v

in cmd I get the same problem that when I installed ionic.

It shows me the version and it shows me this error I copied from the CMD. You can see different folders and how it makes the problem

> C:\Users\adirz>npm -v
>   4.0.5
>
> C:\Users\adirz>ionic -v
>   2.1.18
>
> C:\Users\adirz>cd myapps
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps>cd haversami
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>npm -v
>   3.10.9
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>ionic -v 'ionic' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami>

Answer (score 0):

Install **npm** locally in your project folder

```
npm install npm --save-dev
```